# Validate UTC date in Postman

Tags: postman

-In post call, entered the following in pre-request script

`postman.setGlobalVariable('Date1', (new Date()).toISOString());`

-From the get call response, getting Date2

-I need to validate whether Date2 > Date1. it's in UTC format "2021-04-22T14:34:00.262Z"

How to do this in Postman? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let moment = require('moment')
pm.expect(moment("2021-04-23T02:22:53.610Z").isAfter("2019-04-23T02:22:53.610Z")).to.be.true
pm.expect(moment("2021-04-23T02:22:53.610Z").isBefore("2019-04-23T02:22:53.610Z")).to.be.true
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/ is supported in postman , you could use that .